# Querying Solr with field = string1 OR string2

Tags: search, solr

I have built an index with Solr such that the following query returns a result:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=username_s:*js*
```

Now I'd like to extend the results set, and in addition to *js* I'd like to add *pa* (i.e users which have "pa" as the part of their name).

I tried different things like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=username_s:"*js* AND *pa*"
```

Just can't get it working.
Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: yep great. that's the answer, plz answer below. Rene maybe you know where there's some documentation about querying thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `q=username_s:(*js* *pa*)`, if your default-operator is set to OR (in solrconfig.xml). Alternatively you can use `q=username_s:(*js* OR *pa*)`.

See [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) for more info's.